# Get all birthday greetings

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get all birthday greetings posted on my timeline, but Facebook grouped them in just 1 history. Using Graph API `2.8/me/feed`, the first item is:

```
{
  "story": "Eliane Coster and 69 others wrote on your Timeline.",
  "created_time": "2016-11-23T03:01:14+0000",
  "id": "775101715895356_1283579841714205"
}
```

Using `2.8/775101715895356_1283579841714205` returns only the last message, and no link/id to the 68 remaining.

So, my question is: how can I get the others messages? Or, at least, the ids.

(Not all friends tagged me, so I cant use `2.8/me/tagged`)

Answer (score 0):

As you can read in the docs, there is no other endpoint for it: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/user/feed

In other words: If you don´t get it with the feed endpoint, there is most likely no way to get it.